# Binary file reading

Tags: c, fread, fseek

I am dealing with a code which reading data from a binary file. The code is given here. Would anyone please make clear to me the role of fseek and fread here.

```
fc = fopen(CLOUDS_FILE, "rb");
if (fc == NULL){ fputs("File open error.\n", stderr); exit(1); }
crs = aux[CLRS];
fpos = (int) (pixel[2]*crs*crs + pixel[1]*crs + pixel[0]);
flsz = sizeof(fd);
fseek(fc, fpos*flsz, 0);
rd = fread((void *) &fd, flsz, 1, fc);
if (rd != 1){ fputs("Read error.\n", stderr); exit(1); }
fclose(fc);
```

Answer (score 1):

fseek() changes the file offset. fread() reads data starting from the current offset, incrementing the offset by the number of elements read.

(Or is the question something else entirely? I mean, the above is something one can trivially figure by reading the manpages)

Comment: C language has extensive manpages, which should be the recommended the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

The binary file reading is done with an internal 'pointer', just like text editors have a cursor position when editing something. When opening the file in reading mode (using `fopen`) the pointer will be at the beginning of the file. Read operations (like `fread`, which will read a specified number of bytes from the stream) start reading at the pointer position and usually advance the pointer when they're done. If it is only necessary to read a specific part of the file, it is possible to manually set the pointer to a certain (relative or absolute) position, this is what `fseek` is used for.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);
```

The  fseek()  function  sets the file position indicator for the stream
pointed to by stream.  The new position, measured in bytes, is obtained
by  adding offset bytes to the position specified by whence.  If whence
is set to SEEK_SET, SEEK_CUR, or SEEK_END, the offset  is  relative  to
the  start of the file, the current position indicator, or end-of-file,
respectively.

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

The  function  fread()  reads  nmemb  elements of data, each size bytes
long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at  the  loca‐
tion given by ptr.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, fseek is forwarding the "read from" index in the file to a calculated offset in CLOUDS_FILE, while fread is reading one object of size sizeof(fd) (whatever fd is, as that's not in your pasted code) into fd.